# How to display an option from a selectbox?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a table that shows the **time** and the **task** a user has to do.
All this is saved in a database. For each row and column there is a `selectbox`(Usernames) and an `<input>`(for comments).

Here is a screenshot: http://snag.gy/NYwsJ.jpg

The `name` of each `selectbox` is the id of the **time** and **task**

`echo "<select name='" . $x['idTask'] . "-" . $y['idTime'] . "'>`
(e.g: name="1_23")

The problem is when I load the page it is supposed to display all the records that are already saved in the database.

For the `<select>` I tried using this an `if`:

```
if ($x["fiUser"] == $z["idUser"]){echo "selected";}
```

And here is the table:

```
                <?php
            echo"<div class='dv_Table'><table><tr><th></th>";
            foreach (SelectTime() as $r) {
                echo "<th>" . $r['dtTime'] . "</th>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<form method='post'>";
            $userselect = "";

            foreach (SelectCalTask() as $x) {
                echo "<tr><td>" . $x['dtTask'] . "</td>";
                foreach (SelectTime() as $y) {
                    echo "<td>";

                    echo "<select name='" . $x['idTask'] . "-" . $y['idTime'] . "'>
                    <option value='0'> -- None -- </option> ";
                    foreach (SelectUser_Name() as $z) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $z["idUser"] . "'";
                        if ($x["fiUser"] == $z["idUser"]) {
                            echo "selected";
                        } echo" >" . $z["dtFirstName"] . " " . $z["dtLastName"] . "</option> ";
                    }
                    echo "   </select>
                        <input type='text' name='" . $x['idTask'] . "_" . $y['idTime'] . "' value='" . "_" . $y['idTime'] . "'></td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table></div>";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='updateCalendar' value='Update'></form>";
            ?>
```

Better, would be if could send an `Update` query right after the "onchange" or right after finishing the comment in the `input`.
Is that possible ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*

> Better, would be if could send an Update query right after the
>   "onchange" or right after finishing the comment in the input. Is that
>   possible ?

*

Why not?

```
$('.yourValue').on('change', function (e) {
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/path-to-update-query",
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm using php functions to execute my querys what path should I use ? How to select the function ? (PATH :  ../Includes/functions.php). And should I use GetElmentById for the value ?